# Can someone explain this definition of Kundalini by Vivekananda?

Tags: vivekananda, kundalini

Here below is what Vivekananda tells about Kundalini in his book "Raja Yoga". He says: when we observe things, we memorise and store sensations about these things, and from this store we get dreams and imagination. But then he says that **all this stored energy is Kundalini**. I thought that Kundalini was something different.

> Now, even after a long time I can remember the city. This memory is
> exactly the same phenomenon, only it is in a milder form. But whence
> is the action that sets up even the milder form of similar vibrations
> in the brain? Not certainly from the primary sensations. Therefore it
> must be that **the sensations are coiled up somewhere**, and they, by
> their acting, bring out the mild reaction which we call dream
> perception.
>
> **Now the centre where all these residual sensations are, as it were, stored up, is called the Mūlādhāra, the root receptacle, and the
> coiled-up energy of action is Kuṇḍalinī, "the coiled up"**. ... Now,
> if this coiled-up energy be roused and made active, and then
> consciously made to travel up the Suṣumnā canal, as it acts upon
> centre after centre, a tremendous reaction will set in. When a minute
> portion of energy travels along a nerve fibre and causes reaction from
> centres, the perception is either dream or imagination. But when by
> the power of long internal meditation the vast mass of energy stored
> up travels along the Suṣumnā, and strikes the centres, the reaction is
> tremendous, immensely superior to the reaction of dream or
> imagination, immensely more intense than the reaction of
> sense-perception. It is super-sensuous perception. And when it reaches
> the metropolis of all sensations, the brain, the whole brain, as it
> were, reacts, and the result is the full blaze of illumination, the
> perception of the Self.

Comment: . I thought that Kundalini was something different.?? What did you think it was?? Kundalini is explained variously as it's effects are widespread and varied. See you can describe coffee as warm liquid, brown liquid, liquid inside a cup, stimulant etc. The same thing can be described variously on its effect. Here Swamiji is desciribing the expirrience generating potential of Kundalini. It doesn't mean that's all Kundalini is.

Comment: @MrGreenGold «Kundalini, the serpent power or mystic fire, is the primordial energy or Sakti that lies dormant or sleeping in the Muladhara Chakra»  «the great pristine force which underlies all organic and inorganic matter»  «Kundalini is the cosmic power in individual bodies»  «It is the coiled-up, sleeping Divine Sakti that lies dormant in all beings»